# f-String interpolation not just when run

Tags: python

Is there a way to make it so that the content of a string always depend on an environment variable (and not just interpolated when the line that defines the string is run) ?

I'm probably not clear, so here's an example of what I want

```
my_variable = "foo"
my_string = f"The variable is {my_variable}"
print(my_string)

# Output :
```

> The answer is foo

```
my_variable = "bar"
# Note I'm not doing "my_string = ..." again
print(my_string)

# The desired output :
```

> The variable is bar

```
# The actual output :
```

> The variable is foo

Comment: `x = f"The variable is {my_variable}"` is essentially equivalent to `x = "The variable is " + my_variable`. This is by design to avoid security vulnerabilities. If you don't want this behaviour then you'll have to use another mechanism, like using a normal string (not f-string) with formatting and calling the `.format` method on it each time.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
my_variable="foo"
my_string = "a string containing {somevar}".format(somevar=my_variable)
print(my_string)
my_variable="bar"
my_string = "a string containing {somevar}".format(somevar=my_variable)
print(my_string)
```

Returns:

```
a string containing foo
a string containing bar
```

[edit] ahh I see, you want to remove the second explicit re-evaluation of `my_string` and print out the result as if it had been evaluated?

You could *pretend* not to re-evaluate the string by defining `my_string` as a function and feeding it a my_variable parameter. It'll look the way you want, but will be doing the same in the background.

```
def my_string(somevar):
    return "a string containing {somevar}".format(somevar=somevar)

my_variable="foo"
print(my_string(my_variable))
my_variable="bar"
#my_string = "a string containing {somevar}".format(somevar=my_variable)
print(my_string(my_variable))
```

Returns:

```
a string containing foo
a string containing bar
```